# Make calls from another Android phone over Internet

Tags: google-play-store, calls, stock-android, internet

I have 2 Android phones. First phone is in country **A**. Of course it has an Internet connection over WiFi. Second phone is in another country **B**, as me.
So, I need to make phone calls while I'm in country **B** (over Internet) *remotely* using the phone and its sim-card, which is in counrty **A**.
What Android software do I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some screen mirroring softwares like Airdroid or Mobizen for Samsung and make the calls from country B using your computer. But you need to configure it before hand. You can login from the same account in your mobile and computer so that you can access it even when they're in different networks

Comment: But Airdroid, for example, works only over wifi...

Comment: You can sync your Facebook or Google account and sign in from it

Comment: From another computer?

Comment: Yes. Use your same account to login on both your phone and computer. I think it works that way

Comment: and what about Mobizen? Can I do the same with it? And can Airdroid send sound?

Comment: I'm not sure if Mobizen works for other than Samsung but yeah. It works in your case.

Comment: @MohitVellanki Could you please [edit] your answer and integrate the details from the comments?